# Is there any way to build ZeroMQ for emscripten?

Tags: c++, zeromq, emscripten, webassembly

When I try to build zeromq c library to Emscripten, It produces an error which states that dynamic linking error : no such file or directory.
Is there any way to compile existing c library to Emscripten. Should i add any arguments along with the emconfigure step?

I tried to compile with the guidance of emscripten official page. Unfortunately i am still unclear about the build steps of c library to emscripten.

```
wget https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/releases/download/v4.2.2/zeromq-4.2.2.tar.gz
./autogen.sh
emconfigure ./configure
emmake make 
emmake make install 
ldconfig
```

> Shared Error: No dynamic linking  Shared Error : No input files

Comment: without digging into it, compiling without dynamic linking probably requires significantly changing the build. But even if you do that emscripten is generally limited to whatever APIs your target platform supports. If that platform is the browser there is no raw networking available in the browser to run ZeroMQ over AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently its not possible to build zeromq with emscripten.Possible way is you need to write your own zmq library that supports emscripten standard or have a look on other sources for building zeromq.